# Извлечение текста из строки содержащей HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

В функцию на обработку поступает текст, к примеру вот такой:

```
привет здесь <a href="site.ru">http://site.ru</a> есть ссылка
```

Как можно обработать текст, чтобы результат получился такой

```
привет здесь http://site.ru есть ссылка
```

То есть мы берем ссылку, и отбрасываем от неё HTML тэги, оставляя сам текст ссылки.

Comment: Вот к чему приводят фреймворки

Answer (score 1):

```js
var el = $('#src');
var text = el.text();
console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="src">привет <b>здесь</b> <a href="site.ru">http://site.ru</a> есть ссылка</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Это не стоит делать регулярными выражениями, с этим прекрасно справляется DOM.

```js
// откуда-то получается текст
var text = document.querySelector(".text").innerHTML;

// Создаём фейковый элемент
var fakeDiv = document.createElement("div");
// Присваиваем innerHTML
fakeDiv.innerHTML = text;

// Извлекаем результат
console.log(fakeDiv.innerText);
```

```html
<div class="text">привет здесь <a href="site.ru">http://site.ru</a> есть ссылка</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно регулярным выражением удалить все теги

```js
let html = document.querySelector(".text").innerHTML;
let trueText = html.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '');
console.log(trueText);
```

```html
<div class="text">привет здесь <a href="site.ru">http://site.ru</a> есть ссылка</div>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]